# How to use predict() function in Markov chain

Tags: r, debugging, predict, markov-chains

I am trying to create a function sing Markov Chain to make future predictions, but it's giving me a warning message. Please help.

My R version is 3.6.1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, we do not have access to your data object, `mcWeather`. Please [edit] your question to include the output from the R command `dput(mcWeather)`.

Comment: Please include the packages you are using, since `rmarkovchain` is not included in base R.

Comment: @duckmayr I have added the entire code of mcWeather generation

Comment: @MartinGal included the version RStudio
Version 1.2.5001

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem

The issue you're having is that you're passing a vector of length > 1 to the argument `t0` in `rmarkovchain()`, when it expects `t0` to be of length *exactly* one. Think about your predict function:

```
predict <- function(initial_state, t) {
    prediction <- rmarkovchain(n = t, object = mcWeather, t0 = initial_state)[t] 
    prediction 
}
```

When a vector of length greater than one is passed as the argument `initial_state`, then `rmarkovchain()` gets a value for `t0` that is more than one element, which causes problems with `markovchainSequence()`, which it calls.

Why does this cause a problem? We can see from `help("markovchainSequence")` that it expects `t0` is of length one:

> Arguments
>
> ...[Some content omitted]...
>
> t0    **The** initial state

(emphasis added). So, when it does some checking about the `t0` value, it uses `if()`, which expects a logical vector of **only** length one. That's why when it checks

```
if (!(t0 %in% markovchain@states))
```

if you've passed a vector of length more than one as `t0`, you get a warning; the `if()` function expects only one logical value, so it will use only the *first* logical value in the resulting vector. That's why you get the warning, it's also why all your predictions are the same.

#### The Solution

So, how do we fix it? We alter your function slightly to handle vectors of length greater than one for `initial_state`:

```
predict <- function(initial_state, t) {
    prediction <- sapply(initial_state, function(state) {
        rmarkovchain(n = t, object = mcWeather, t0 = state)[t]
    })
    return(prediction)
}
```

This goes across the values passed in `initial_state` and predicts for them one at a time, as `markovchainSequence()` would expect. We can see that it works as expected:

```
x <- data.frame("AccountNo" = 1:5, 
                "CurrentState" = c("sunny", "sunny", "rain" , "cloudy" ,"rain"), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

set.seed(42)
x$Prediction3 <- predict(x$CurrentState,3)
x

  AccountNo CurrentState Prediction3
1         1        sunny       sunny
2         2        sunny       sunny
3         3         rain       sunny
4         4       cloudy        rain
5         5         rain       sunny
```